# Where has Microsoft's WPF/Silverlight Charting gone in .NET 4.0?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, charts

Forgive me for being a little naive perhaps, but it seems that System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting has vanished from VS2010, and blend 4.  I'm trying to make a bar graph with a line overlayed, but can't even get started because I can't find the appropriate controls.

I know I could use an external graphing package, but I'd like to try the inbuilt controls first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention Blend so I assume that you are refering to the WPF/Silverlight chart controls.

The `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace is part of the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/). You will have to download this toolkit and reference it from your project.

Comment: I've not got that .dll, there's system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit, which seems to have done the trick, thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 3):

*The question has been clarified to indicate it is about WPF controls. The answer below refers to the Winforms and Asp.net chart controls. I'm leaving it here in case other people find it useful.*

---

The original MS Chart controls were never part of the framework. They are an separate project.

You can download them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en).

There is also more info on their [project page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

There is an addon to the IDE, ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1D69CE13-E1E5-4315-825C-F14D33A303E9&displaylang=en)), but it's for VS2008, I don't know if it will work with 2010. I would assume they are going to update it at some point, but there doesn't seem to be any information on when that will happen.

---

I stand corrected, .Net 4.0 apparently now has [built in chart controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx). You shouldn't need to install anything. You'll need to make sure you are targeting framework 4.0.

Comment: your edit is incorrect. the [built in chart controls] link is for ASP.NET and WinForms, **NOT** WPF.

Comment: @jberger - Thanks. The original question was less clear. I've updated the answer to reflect the question edit. I'll leave it here rather than delete it though in case other people are looking for the winforms/asp.net chart controls.