# WPF Toolkit in .net 4.0

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Is WPF Toolkit included in .net 4.0? I'm interested in using charts from WPF Toolkit and would like to ask if the charts are available in .net 4.0 or do I have to download WPF Toolkit?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728728/where-has-microsofts-wpf-silverlight-charting-gone-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not included, so you still need to download them separately (or use some other third party charting library)